# How can I protect my static website stack from DDoS attacks?

Tags: security, proxy, dns, reverse-proxy, ddos

As a thought experiment, I am seeking to design an affordable static website stack that does not have single points of failure, is distributed, durable, secure, and very fast. My basic blueprint is as follows:

- Primary and secondary managed anycast DNS (NSONE and Dyn respectively)
- Primary static website (AWS S3) and failover static website (Rackspace)
- Multi-CDN distribution on Cloudfront, Azure, Softlayer, and Rackspace (accomplished using NSONE's filter chain)

Now, the fact that the vast majority of this blueprint uses pay-for-what-you-use services makes the stack affordable and scalable. However, the single glaring vulnerability that I see is the potential for financial denial of service (FDoS) attacks that abuse the stack and run up a user's bill until they are forced to take their site offline.

As such, various DDoS attacks need to be accounted for and mitigated in order to prevent abuse. Common DDoS reverse proxy services are problematic for two reasons. First, they sit between the DNS server and the web server, thereby not protecting the DNS from abuse. Secondly, there are methods of discovering the obscured web server's IP through various leaks that occur (less of an issue on S3 and Rackspace given that the services don't use static IPs, and you could  limit access to just your CDNs). GRE tunneling prevents these leaks and is possible with some higher end DDoS services, but this still doesn't protect the DNS.

So it seems that a solution that sits in front of the managed DNS service is what is needed. Perhaps setting up a DNS proxy server that sits on a DDoS filtered network that forwards scrubbed traffic on to the managed DNS provider's network where legitimate queries are given responses? Can this be accomplished using BIND forwarding? If so, to avoid the DNS proxy from being a single point of failure, a small/diverse anycast DNS proxy network using small instances could be established. Assuming this is an effective solution, it is a bit more work, but presumably still far less expensive than enterprise DDoS solutions.

Okay, so this begs the question, could a potential attacker still attack your managed DNS with a DNS proxy server in front of it? Are there any blatantly obvious avenues of attack remaining? I see a reactive need to create rules for CDN distributions in response to the specifics of an attack. In that vein, is there a means to prevent the mass request of files to run up bandwidth if the CDN itself doesn't have anti-DDoS filters in place, aside from creating your own rules?

Well, thank you for enduring my thought experiment. Again, I am merely looking to find the best solution that is without single points of failure, is affordable, distributed, durable, secure, and very fast. Thank you once again, and I look forward to hearing your technical input!

Comment: DNS poisoning and reverse proxy are client-side related issues and its outside of your grasp to solve it. Your best shot is to use SSL with a signed certificate, and this is still not 100% guaranteed. Some spywares create self-signed certificates and add them to the trusted certificates list on the run as the client browses the Internet, they are only aware of the fraud if they inspect the trusted certificates storage.

Comment: My question is, what criteria do you have for discovering abuse without mistakenly tagging legitimate traffic as abusive? Until you figure that out, it is somewhat difficult to figure out how you would go about preventing abuse. So I would seek to answer that question first, then you can come up with a more technical game plan that fits those needs.

Comment: Also, would it be reasonable for whoever uses this blueprint to set a 'scale limit'? Where they basically say 'it can scale but only up to this point'.